# How the address of pointer that holds the address of array are same?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Here `p` is a integer pointer that can hold the address of `int` variable, but it also has a memory address - where it is stored.

let
  base address of array `a = 1002`
  address of pointer `p = 2008`

when we write: `int *p=a;   //p points to the base address of array a`
and `int **r=&p;            //means *r points to the address of p`

how `*r` points to the address of `a`, it should point to address of `p`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *p =a;
    int **r = &p;
    printf("%p %p", *r, a);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the same ? You let `r` point to the address where `p` is stored and then print `*r`, so obviously that is `p`, which you assigned to be `a`

Comment: It should be int *p = &a; or else it is an invalid conversion

Comment: @DevangJayachandran: `int [3]` decays to `int*`

Comment: Oh right sorry! My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that

```
int *p=a;
```

means that `a` and `p` are now pointing to same address.

Also, it is `r` that points to `p` (is the address of `p`) and not `*r`.

Thus to print the address of `p` simply use `r` instead of `*r` in `printf()`.

```
printf("%p %p", r, a);
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `printf` in not correct. It should be `r` to print the address `r` points to:

```
printf("%p %p", r, a);
```

By using `*r`, you deference `r` (ie, jump to the address `r` is pointing to) and thus printing the address of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

What is below?

```
 int **r = &p;
```

Basically using above, `r` holds address of `p` right?
So if you dereference `r`, like you do `*r`, it will try
to retrieve value stored at address of `p` right? Which is `a`.

Note: You need to cast to `void*` in printf:

```
 printf("%p %p", (void*)*r, (void*) a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't ->-> same as ->

When you say,

```
int *p = a;
```

it means, P is pointing to a, or P holds the address of a.

Same in case of `int **r=&p;`

R holds the address of P, 
had you used `printf("%p %p", r, a);`, you would have got the address of P.

but since you are dereferencing r, you got the address of a.